# Read txt file in if Statement in nodejs

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm saving a some variable as array of object in txt file , the question is how can i read them and compare it with another variable in for loop .

Thanks .

The format that i Saved in txt file :

```
[{"sekke":"445,675","halfsekke":"145,600"}]
```

And the code that i want to read is :
**NodeJs:**

```
var array = fs.readFileSync('data.txt').toString().split("\n");
            console.log(array[0]['sekke'])
            for (var key in array[0]['sekke']) {
                console.log("key " + key + " has value " + array);
            }
```

which is wrong , how can i read achive something like this ?

```
if (array['sekke] == 100){
console.log("is ok");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the below code:

```
fs.readFile('data.txt', 'utf8', function read(err, data) {
       if (err) {
         throw err;
       }
       data = JSON.parse(data);
       var dataObject = data[0];
       for (i=0;i<Object.keys(dataObject).length;i++) {
           var ss = dataObject[i];
           var key = Object.keys(ss);
          for(varj=0;j<ss[key];j++){
             //your if condition logic
          }
       }  
    });
```

Comment: thanks , but i want to loop in all variable and add if statement

Comment: yes i just solved it with something like this : fs.readFile('data.txt', 'utf8', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
     throw err;
    }
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data);
    for (var key in data) {
     //your logic goes here
     console.log(key)
     if(parseInt(data[0]['sekke']) == parseInt(oldNumberTwo)){
      console.log("same");
     }else{
      console.log("changed");
     }
    }
   });

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the string back to JSON if you want to use it like an object. 
If your file is a collection of arrays (1 array per line) then split it by \n like you do and then parse it with `JSON.parse`. You would need to run that on each line separately thought so use a map or a loop.
If your file however is one big array of objects then just read it in and then parse the whole thing with `JSON.parse`.

Also, consider using the asynchronous version of readFile as using readFileSync will block the whole node.js app while it's reading (that becomes a problem as the file gets bigger)